# I wonder if $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F) \leq S_{d_1} \times S_{d_2} \times S_{d_3} \times \cdots \times S_{d_n} $ or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ satisfy $f(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)\cdots f_n(x)$, where $f_i(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$.

My opinion is:

If $E$ is splitting field of $f(x)$ and we denote degree of $f_i(x)$ by $d_i$, then $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F) \leq S_{d_1} \times S_{d_2} \times S_{d_3} \times \cdots \times S_{d_n} $ ($\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$ is Galois group of $f(x)$ and $S_{n}$ is permutation group of $n$)

My Question: Is this collect?

If not, is there similar theorem of this opinion? what condition do I need?

For example, if $f(x)$ is separable, then this is true?

Comment: Sure this is correct $Gal(E/F)$ is a group of permutation of the roots of $f$ and $f_i(\alpha_j) = 0, f_i \in F[x]$ implies $\forall \sigma\in Gal(E/F),f_i(\sigma(\alpha_j)) = \sigma(f_i(\alpha_j))=0$ so $Gal(E/F)$ sends the roots of each $f_i$ to themselves.